# error while compiling Qt soap client

Tags: web-services, qt, gsoap

I was trying to use qt for creating client side of a web service with generated gSoap files.
after adding neccessary files and stdsoap2 files and also adding :

LIBS     += C:\Qt2\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a

to .pro file.
but after that i got the following errors :

C:\Qt2\Qt5.0.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\gSoap3\stdsoap2.cpp:8845: error: undefined reference to `namespaces'

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

what should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[What's the difference between .lib and .a files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337949/whats-the-difference-between-lib-and-a-files)

Try putting a `.lib` instead of a `.a`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply
but unfortunately Qt Cannot recognize libws2_32.lib