# Qt error when adding library - no rule to make target

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, static-libraries

I am trying to build a plain c++ qmake project in Qt, I have linked the library required by my code using the built in "add library..." wizard. I have set the library as static.

This then modifies my .pro file with this additional text:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lfusionTrack32

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./fusionTrack32.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./libfusionTrack32.a
```

I then try to build the project and this error is returned:

```
mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target'//icnas1.cc.ic.ac.uk/hd1714/ftk_basic/./libfusionTrack32.a', needed by 'release\ftk_basic.exe'.  Stop.
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

I have am trying to add the 32bit library but I get the same error when trying to link the 64 library as well. The library is a .lib import library. I currently have all the files on the same folder. I using windows 7, minGW 32, g++.

*also* if I delete the line for the .a file ( that I don't not want ):

```
 else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/./libfusionTrack32.a
```

then instead I get the two errors:

```
 cannot find -lfusionTrack32
 error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The library is not named libfusionTrack32.a ?

Comment: unfortunately not @perencia , the library is called fusionTrack32.lib, I believe the .a files are for unix and .lab are the equivalent for windows...[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337949/whats-the-difference-between-lib-and-a-files)

Comment: hence my confusion at why it would included this in the .pro file after I unchecked the boxes for mac and linux in the wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you can directly modify the `.pro` file by yourself not the wizard. So, please first undo all changes applied to the `.pro` file and then simply add the library using the following commands:

```
# Absolute address of the .lib file
LIBS += c:/mylib/mylib.lib

# Absolute address of its header files (if any)
INCLUDEPATH += c:/mylib/include
```

That's it! [more info](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)

Comment: Frogatto I have done as you said, I know get several error messages, mainly for `undefined reference` and also some lovely `in function` errors. However these functions are not in the library so I think you fixed it, Congratulations!! you did it :) Thank you very much