# Missing names in lua5.3 dll file

Tags: c++, windows, lua

Under Visual Studio (2017) I am trying to script a C++ program with Lua 5.3 but the linker does not find three function names referenced in my C++ source file:

> unresolved external symbol _lua_close
>
> unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
>
> unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate

I took the C++ source from the [Lua website](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaApiExample).

I downloaded the Lua 5.3 dynamic library which does not come with an import library so I created the import library with the MSVC tools like so:

```
dumpbin /exports E:\Documents\Programmation\Lua5.3\lua53.dll
```

From the output of dumpbin, I copied the 146 names in a new file "mylua53lib.def" and ran lib to generate the .lib file like so:

```
lib /def:E:\Documents\Programmation\Lua5.3\mylua53lib.def /OUT:E:\Documents\Programmation\Lua5.3\mylua53lib.lib /machine:x86
```

The three function names that the linker does not find are indeed not appearing in the output of the dumpbin command.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to do there; normally, you'd just have to `extern "C" { #include <lua.h> }` and it should work.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Well as I said I took the example from the Lua website so I included the three headers. However I indeed put the three include directives in a extern "C" { ... }.

Comment: *which does not come with an import library* - wait, what? This doesn't sound correct. I don't remember ever having to jump through such hoops. If you download the binaries from e.g. [here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/), it comes with headers, DLL and the `.a` file (which is effectively the lib file).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz So changing the .a extension to .lib is enough? Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary distribution of Lua intented for dynamic linking on Windows should come with two binary files:

- a DLL file with the actual Lua code
- a library file with the method stubs delegating to the DLL

Sometimes the library file will come with an `.a` extension, which is more common on Linux (as opposed to `.lib` on Windows). If it's a Windows build, though, you can simply pass that file as a linker dependency and it will work just fine. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337949/whats-the-difference-between-lib-and-a-files) deals with differences between the two conventions.

As a side note, in order to make it work, if you create a C++ project in Visual Studio, and add a `Source.cpp` as it suggests by default, you'll still get unresolved externals. This is due to the fact that while the C sources compile as C++ code just fine, the linker will expect mangled names for the definitions of the C functions used. This can be prevented by either compiling the file as C code, or, preferrably, by telling it that the names from Lua headers should be unmangled in the linked library using `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {

#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

}
```

Comment: Of course, the next preferred step would be to replace `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` with either `cstdlib` and `cstdio`, or even better, to replace those with proper C++ code, if the project is intended to be written in C++ and not C.